# How do ASP.Net controls read from their data sources?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a need to display information on my pages in a way that none of the standard ASP.net controls support. In order to do this, I've created my own controls, and had to reproduce some of the functionality of the ASP.Net form controls - specifically their capacity to bind to a number of different data sources.

According to the documentation, controls can bind to any data source supporting the IEnumerable, ICollection, or IListSource interfaces. Now I know you can bind controls directly to a SQLDataReader, but I can't work out which interface the class conforms to that allows this to work. IIRC it implements iEnumerable but for enumerating columns, not rows.

I want my own objects to be able to consume these data sources, and I have a way of doing it (using reflection to access properties dynamically, etc), but since the .Net framework already does this, I'm hoping there's an object already part of the framework, eliminating the need for me to roll my own. Questions:

1) Which condition does SQLDataReader meet to allow it to be used as a data source for ASP.Net controls?
2) Is there a class that can iterate over the allowed ASP.Net data sources row by row, avoiding the need to roll my own?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this exactly answers your question, but you can iterate over SqlDataReader using DbDataRecord class (and in this case IEnumerable iterates over rows) e.g. (VB.NET):

```
For Each rec As Data.Common.DbDataRecord In MyReader
   'access fields by rec(ordinal) or rec(FieldName)
Next
```